# How to change my protobufs config in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, protocol-buffers, intellij-14

I installed the Google Prototype Buffers plug-in. I got the output path wrong. How do I change it? I can find no way to get the configuration window back.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the command line to compile .proto files, you could specify "--java_out=desired/path". So the final command may look like : **'protoc --proto_path=src --java_out=build/gen src/foo.protobuf'**